# Request for reference for currents

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

Do you know an introductory book (end of undergraduate/beginning of graduate) about currents in the sense of de Rham? Or even better, a video lecture on that topic? I didn't find it on youtube. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~tien-cuong.dinh/Cours2005/Master/cours.pdf

Comment: Thanks. That is a good one but it doesn't have any proof, only the results. I would like to see also the proofs.

Comment: Try looking at Demailly's "Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry"